# Add custom fields to "Edit vendor" page - Woocommerce product vendors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, vendor

I’m trying to add fields to the “Edit Vendor” page of the product Vendors plugin of Woocommerce.

For a product I used:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data','woocommerce_product_custom_fields');

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{
    global $product_object;

    echo '<div class=" product_custom_field ">';

    // Custom Product Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id'          => 'data',
        'label'       => __('data:', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true'
    ));

}
```

To add custom woocommerce_wp_text_input, and then:

`$product->update_meta_data("customField", sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']));`

To set it.

Is there something similar for the Vendor edit page ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "vendor page"? is that something default in woocommerce or you mean this plugin's page (https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/)?

Comment: I was refering to the "product vendors" plugin, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to [Woocommerce Product Vendor](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/) plugin ?

Then you can add Custom Field to Edit Vendor page, by add following code.

```
add_action('wcpv_product_vendors_edit_form_fields', 'edit_vendor_custom_fields', 10);

function edit_vendor_custom_fields($term) {
    $vendor_data = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'vendor_data', true );
    $custom_field = isset( $vendor_data['custom_field'] ) ? $vendor_data['custom_field'] : '';
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="vendor_data[custom_field]" id="custom_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr($custom_field); ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

[image]